# Validating input within Thymeleaf’s th:object in Spring Boot controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

I’m using Kotlin, Spring Boot 2.0.4, and Thymeleaf to build a teaching project.

The gist of it is simple:

First, showForm() populates model with input options and returns view:

```
@GetMapping
fun showForm(model: Model): String {
    model.addAttribute(
        "options", 
        listOf(
            Option("1", "Option 1"), 
            Option("2", "Option 2")
        )
    )
    model.addAttribute("design", Design()) // This will be used for th:object
    return "form"
}
```

Second, view generates checkboxes for options:

```
<form method="POST" th:object="${design}">

...

    <div th:each="option: ${options}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" th:value="${option.id}" />
        ...
    </div>

...

</form>
```

Finally, controller validates submitted form and, if there are errors, returns the original form:

```
@PostMapping
fun processForm(@Valid design: Design, result: BindingResult): String {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "form"
    }
    return "redirect:/somewhere/else"
}
```

The problem I’m having is that whenever Spring bounces me back with errors, my option checkboxes disappear. It seems to me, that model attributes seem to become lost.

And if I try to repopulate model with attributes before sending back with errors, the errors themself are lost.

How do I implement validation so that both model attributes and errors persist despite validation errors?

Comment: When there are errors, only add `options` back onto the model.  Don't add `design`.

Comment: @Metroids This has worked, thank you.